# Build job in Jenkins through python script SSL connection

Tags: python, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I want to build a job in jenkins through python script.I am totally new to python.I am using below method from python-jenkins.my jenkins url is https.

```
 server = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)
```

and i am getting

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='{myjenkinsur}', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

how can I connect through SSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `ssl_verifiy` to `False`

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token, ssl_verify=False)
```

If you get error with the above command, then try the below one

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(ci_jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)
server._session.verify = False
```